# Kibana 4 - numeric fields

Tags: kibana

Very new to this. Importing with logstash a csv file with 2 columns, like this

```
lun 16 feb 15; 3,00
mar 17 feb 15; 4,00
```

...

1st colum is date, 2nd is Humidity

I then want to produce a very simple grapf with kibana showing Data on X, Humidity value on Y - superbasic stuff

Looks like I am not able to have the 2 fileds imported properly or recognized by Kibana as field1: date   field2: number

here is what I get

```
{
  "_index": "prova-2015.02.12",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AUt9lYFzON9412qlRdDl",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "message": [
      "lun 16 feb 15;3,00"
    ],
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-02-12T11:38:43.283Z",
    "host": "ELK-Dev-and-Demo",
    "path": "/home/elkadmin/Documenti/Analytics/data-value.csv",
    "Data": "lun 16 feb 15",
    "HUM": "3,00"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1423741123283
    ],
    "Data": [
      "15"
    ]
  }
}
```

Still in Kibana 4 looks like the numeris value is interpreted like a string. What am I doing wrong in importing it?

Logstash conf file

```
input {  
      file {
          path => "/home/elkadmin/Documenti/Analytics/data-value.csv"
          start_position => "beginning"
      }
}

filter {  
    csv {
        columns => ["Data", "HUM"]
        separator => ";"
    }
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
    protocol => "http"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "prova-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        workers => 1
    }
     stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Data file has been saved to csv from an  Excel file ( with proper cells type set for date and number);

```
mer 11 feb 15;1,00
gio 12 feb 15;4,00
ven 13 feb 15;5,60
sab 14 feb 15;8,00
dom 15 feb 15;12,50
lun 16 feb 15;3,00
mar 17 feb 15;4,60
mer 18 feb 15;7,00
gio 19 feb 15;2,20
ven 20 feb 15;5,00
sab 21 feb 15;4,50
dom 22 feb 15;2,35
lun 23 feb 15;3,00
mar 24 feb 15;6,00
mer 25 feb 15;9,10
gio 26 feb 15;2,20
```

Final question is also how to define the proper Visualization to show Dates and Values, why in Y do I always get options for Aggregate and not the specific value for a date?

Date histogram on X does not work , Fatal Erro when I select it and apply ( more details in a further Q when I have understood you to have Kibana  recognize date and numbers )

Thanks in advance

F

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that you're doing anything to make these fields be interpreted as anything other than a string.

Two options come to mind:

1. Set [a mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) for the index that specifies 'date' as a date field and 'hum' as an integer.
2. Use logstash's mutate->convert feature (for the int) and date{} (for the date) to get the fields in the correct format before inserting into elasticsearch.

If you use #1, note that Elasticsearch will drop any record that can't be coerced into the right type.